# Why does Breeze enforce OData 5.2.0?

Tags: odata, breeze

Unfortunately breeze nuget package 1.2.1 seems to be bound to Microsoft.Data.OData 5.2.0.

`Install failed. Rolling back...
Updating 'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.3.0' to 'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.2.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.2.0'.`

Is there a reason for that?
We are already depending on 5.3.0 so we can't go back!

Comment: More the less, BreezeJS should be a javascript library.
I'd rather want you to split it into two different libraries. (server and client (js) side). 

We don't use WebAPI at all, since ODATA support is rather ancient, but instead WCF Data Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We published a updated nuget package [4.0.1](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/4.0.1) to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the Breeze nuget installs the "Microsoft Asp.NET Web Api OData" nuget which in turn has the hard limit of 'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.2.x' ( not 5.3).

That said, I will try to check with MS as to the reason for the limit.

Comment: Microsoft.Data.OData 5.3 is a **prerelease** package.  MS is within its rights to fault your hasty reliance on unreleased s/w. Our hands are kind of tied at the moment. We're trying to get some more information for you ... or some kind of workaround.

Comment: I hasten to add that this is only a problem for folks using Breeze.NET helper components. Anyone not using a .NET server or using a vanilla Web API can proceed by using the BreezeJS JavaScript libraries standalone. You can [download them](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download) from the Breeze website.

Comment: I WAS WRONG. The **Microsoft.Data.OData 5.3.0 is the official stable release**. The heat is on.

Answer (score 1):

### Update 4/1/2013

I am informed that an updated Microsoft.Aspnet.Webapi.odata nuget package 4.0.1 should fix this. Please try it and confirm.

### Original Answer

I have a temporary workaround. I mean **temporary** because the steps I'm about to enumerate require precision and could easily break in future.

I tested them on a sample generated from the currently deployed [Breeze/Knockout SPA template](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/breezeknockout-template) and upgraded successfully to the 1.2.1 version of Breeze. Should work for subsequent Breeze versions (let us know if it doesn't)

Enter the following sequence in the Package Manager Console:

1. Uninstall-Package Microsoft.Aspnet.Webapi.odata  (fortunately this did NOT uninstall dependencies of this particular package, I assume because other packages had the same dependencies)
2. Install-Package Microsoft.Data.OData -Version 5.3.0
3. Install-Package Microsoft.Aspnet.Webapi.odata -pre –IgnoreDependencies
4. Update-Package breeze.webapi –IgnoreDependencies

The "-IgnoreDependencies" switch provides the leverage to shoehorn v.5.3.0 into your solution.

I want to stress again that this is a temporary solution which may only work for a while. I look forward to returning to your SO question and reporting that this advice has been rescinded. I may even delete this answer.

Comment: Until the official release will be the solution, I will vote this work-around!